# iPhone Trying to make a end-of-year count down timer

Tags: ios

I'm trying to have a display of how many days, hours, minutes, and seconds to the end of the year.

My idea was to create a NSDate for the current time and a NSDate for the end of the year.  Then subtract them.

After reading the documentation I saw a method to add, but not subtract 2 NSDates.

There must be a way to make a count down timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss\"];
NSDate *endDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-01-01 00:00:00"];
```

Based on JustSid's comment this seems to be the way to go from here:

```
NSDateComponents *timeDifference = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] 
components: NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit  
fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:endDate options:0];

int days = timeDifference.day;
int hours = timeDifference.hour;
int minutes = timeDifference.minute;
int seconds = timeDifference.second;
```

Comment: Time calculation is a bitch, and more complicated than your solution. `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` are the two classes you want to use for this kind of stuff, they take care of daylight saving time and other nonsense you might come across.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
- (NSString*) getTimeInterval:(NSDate*) start endTime:(NSDate*) end {
    if([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", end] isEqualToString:@"1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"]) {
        end = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    }
    NSTimeInterval interval = [end timeIntervalSinceDate: start];
    int numberOfdays = floor(interval/86400);
    int numberOfHours = floor((interval - numberOfdays*86400) / 3600);
    int numberOfMinutes = floor((interval - numberOfdays*86400 - numberOfHours*3600) / 60);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d d %d h %d m", numberOfdays, numberOfHours, numberOfMinutes];
}
```